# How do I split a file of numbers in java?

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am trying to convert a file full of numbers (9x9) into an a readable array based off columns and rows. It is for a sudoku game builder. The file reads as so:

```
0,0,2,9,8,0,5,0,0
4,0,0,0,7,0,0,1,3
0,3,9,6,0,4,0,7,0
2,0,0,0,5,6,4,0,0
8,4,0,3,0,0,2,0,1
9,0,7,0,0,1,0,8,6
6,0,0,7,0,5,1,3,0
0,9,1,4,0,0,0,0,5
0,2,0,0,3,0,6,0,8
```

Where I'm using the "0's" as blank spaces. I want to split the numbers at the commas so for the first row I want it to read: gameBoard[0] = [0,0,2,9,8,0,5,0,0] or as gameBoard[0][4] = [9]. The array I'm using is gameBoard[][].

Some people told me it would be helpful to include some code I tried so here it is:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                gameBoard[i][j] = game.split(",");
            }
        }
```

This section of code is within a method that is called through a constructor.

Comment: If you tried anything, post it in the question

Comment: Hi AJ, you may find it helpful to include some code you tried to this question, it would definitely make it easier for community to help you and would probably avoid "phew, another homework question" reaction.

Answer (score 3):

A little start-help to a new contributor ..

```
    String[][] gameBoard = new String[9][9];
    File f = new File("zz_play9.txt");               
    try {
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

        String readLine = "";        
        int linecounter =0;
        while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(readLine);
            gameBoard[linecounter++] = readLine.split(",");
        }
        b.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(zz_play9.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I have entered your start-data into a file called zz_play9.txt.

By running the program you get:

```
0,0,2,9,8,0,5,0,0
4,0,0,0,7,0,0,1,3
0,3,9,6,0,4,0,7,0
2,0,0,0,5,6,4,0,0
8,4,0,3,0,0,2,0,1
9,0,7,0,0,1,0,8,6
6,0,0,7,0,5,1,3,0
0,9,1,4,0,0,0,0,5
0,2,0,0,3,0,6,0,8
```

and the array gameBoard[][] holds the desired data. Have fun.

Comment: This is not *"A little start-help to a new contributor"*, this is just posting the solution without saying how the code works. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @akuzminykh Thats right. But readLine.split(",") isn't sooo difficult to find and had a good day - normally it should have been "post first some code you have made yourself already" and I wasn't up to that today ^^.

Comment: @akuzminykh Yeah I was in a rush for another class and kind of skipped over some common courtesy steps here and I regret that, but if its better I'm not copying the code provided I am just looking for a general way to make it work like provided.

Comment: Not including explanation greatly reduce the usefulness of the answer for other people facing the same problem. Answer is correct though